# The order of Ribbon menu items in Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: menu, ribbon, dynamics-crm-2013

Is it possible to change the default order of navigation menu buttons in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013?

In CRM 2013 there is a limitation - an entity displays only 5 buttons on the navigation menu by default. The order of these buttons depends on the need of a button.

Is there some possibility to lift the button up from the end of the Ribbon items list using JavaScript programming or edit customizations.xml? Or this order cannot be changed at all?

Thanks in advance and best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use [Ribbon Workbench](http://www.develop1.net/public/page/Ribbon-Workbench-for-Dynamics-CRM-2011.aspx) to reorder buttons? I use this tool in all my projects and I was able to do it.

Comment: I was looking for ways through which I could reorder buttons without using tools. But cannot find any example how to reorder it programmatically using scripts. It seems I should use Ribbon Workbench nevertheless. Thanks a lot for help, Andrii!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Settings → Customizations → Customize the system → Expand your (entities) → (select the entity where you want to change the order of button on the ribbon) → Forms → Information → *Navigation → Under Common, you can just drag those buttons up and down.

The button that you place on top .... appears on the extreme left of your ribbon.